# Lifting scheme DCT

Tags: c++, image

I'm learning about image processing, and recently came to the DCT part. I made basic floating-point one, but it's rather slow, so I searched for some fast algorithms and found [this](https://thanglong.ece.jhu.edu/Tran/Pub/binDCT.pdf) (page 6). It didn't look hard, but it doesn't work as expected and I can't understand what's wrong.

EDIT Is my code doing what diagram says?

`matrix` is a simple class to work with 2D matrices. It works correctly, including type conversions. Access to element is provided by `operator()`, first argument represents row, second - column, both starting from 0.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpiYU.png) is the same diagram as in document above but it shows steps and temporary variables.

```
[[nodiscard]] svc::matrix<int> svc::forward8x8binDCT2(const svc::matrix<unsigned char>& src_)
{
    svc::matrix<int> tempM = svc::matrix<unsigned char>::toInt(src_);

    int a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7;

    int b0, b1, b2, b3;

    int c0, c1, c2;

    int d0, d1, d2, d3;

    // Transform rows

    for (size_t rowC = 0; rowC < 8; ++rowC)
    {
        // Step 1

        a0 = tempM(rowC, 0) + tempM(rowC, 7);
        a7 = tempM(rowC, 0) - tempM(rowC, 7);
        a1 = tempM(rowC, 1) + tempM(rowC, 6);
        a6 = tempM(rowC, 1) - tempM(rowC, 6);
        a2 = tempM(rowC, 2) + tempM(rowC, 5);
        a5 = tempM(rowC, 2) - tempM(rowC, 5);
        a3 = tempM(rowC, 3) + tempM(rowC, 4);
        a4 = tempM(rowC, 3) - tempM(rowC, 4);

        // Even part
        // Step 3

        b0 = a0 + a3;
        b3 = a0 - a3;
        b1 = a1 + a2;
        b2 = a1 - a2;

        // Step 4

        b0 += b1;
        b1 = (b0 >> 1) - b1;
        b2 = (b3 >> 1) - b2;
        b3 = (b2 >> 1) - b3;

        tempM(rowC, 0) = b0;
        tempM(rowC, 4) = b1;
        tempM(rowC, 6) = b2;
        tempM(rowC, 2) = b3;

        // Odd part
        // Step 2

        c0 = (a6 >> 1) - a5;
        c1 = ((c0 * 3) >> 2) + a6;
        c2 = (c1 >> 1) - c0;

        // Step 3

        d0 = a4 + c2;
        d1 = a4 - c2;
        d2 = a7 - c1;
        d3 = a7 + c1;

        // Step 4

        d0 = (d3 >> 2) - d0;
        d3 = (d0 >> 2) - d3;
        d1 += d2;
        d2 = (d1 >> 1) - d2;

        tempM(rowC, 7) = d0;
        tempM(rowC, 5) = d1;
        tempM(rowC, 3) = d2;
        tempM(rowC, 1) = d3;
    }

    // Transform columns

    for (size_t colC = 0; colC < 8; ++colC)
    {
        // Step 1

        a0 = tempM(0, colC) + tempM(7, colC);
        a1 = tempM(0, colC) - tempM(7, colC);
        a2 = tempM(1, colC) + tempM(6, colC);
        a3 = tempM(1, colC) - tempM(6, colC);
        a4 = tempM(2, colC) + tempM(5, colC);
        a5 = tempM(2, colC) - tempM(5, colC);
        a6 = tempM(3, colC) + tempM(4, colC);
        a7 = tempM(3, colC) - tempM(4, colC);

        // Even part
        // Step 3

        b0 = a0 + a3;
        b3 = a0 - a3;
        b1 = a1 + a2;
        b2 = a1 - a2;

        // Step 4

        b0 += b1;
        b1 = (b0 >> 1) - b1;
        b2 = (b3 >> 1) - b2;
        b3 = (b2 >> 1) - b3;

        tempM(0, colC) = b0;
        tempM(4, colC) = b1;
        tempM(6, colC) = b2;
        tempM(2, colC) = b3;

        // Odd part
        // Step 2

        c0 = (a6 >> 1) - a5;
        c1 = ((c0 * 3) >> 2) + a6;
        c2 = (c1 >> 1) - c0;

        // Step 3

        d0 = a4 + c2;
        d1 = a4 - c2;
        d2 = a7 - c1;
        d3 = a7 + c1;

        // Step 4

        d0 = (d3 >> 2) - d0;
        d3 = (d0 >> 2) - d3;
        d1 += d2;
        d2 = (d1 >> 1) - d2;

        tempM(7, colC) =d0;
        tempM(5, colC) =d1;
        tempM(3, colC) =d2;
        tempM(1, colC) =d3;
    }

    return tempM;
}

[[nodiscard]] svc::matrix<int> svc::inverse8x8binDCT2(const svc::matrix<int>& src_)
{
    svc::matrix<int> tempM(src_);

    int a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7;

    int b0, b1, b2, b3;

    int c0, c1, c2, c3;

    int d0, d1, d2;

    // Transform rows

    for (size_t rowC = 0; rowC < 8; ++rowC)
    {
        // Load values

        a0 = tempM(rowC, 0);
        a1 = tempM(rowC, 1);
        a2 = tempM(rowC, 2);
        a3 = tempM(rowC, 3);
        a4 = tempM(rowC, 4);
        a5 = tempM(rowC, 5);
        a6 = tempM(rowC, 6);
        a7 = tempM(rowC, 7);

        // Even part
        // Step 1

        a1 = (a0 >> 1) - a1;
        a0 = a1 - a0;
        a3 += a2 >> 1;
        a2 = (a3 >> 1) - a2;

        // Step 2

        b0 = a0 + a3;
        b3 = a0 - a3;
        b1 = a1 + a2;
        b2 = a1 - a2;

        // Odd part
        // Step 1

        a6 += (a5 >> 1);
        a5 = a6 - a5;
        a7 += a4 >> 2;
        a4 = (a7 >> 2) - a4;

        // Step 2

        c0 = a4 + a5;
        c1 = a4 - a5;
        c2 = a7 - a6;
        c3 = a7 + a6;

        // Step 3

        d0 = (c2 >> 1) - c1;
        d1 = ((d0 * 3) >> 2) - c2;
        d2 = (d1 >> 2) + d0;

        // Step 4

        tempM(rowC, 0) = b0 + c3;
        tempM(rowC, 1) = b1 + d1;
        tempM(rowC, 2) = b2 + d2;
        tempM(rowC, 3) = b3 + c0;
        tempM(rowC, 4) = b3 - c0;
        tempM(rowC, 5) = b2 - d2;
        tempM(rowC, 6) = b1 - d1;
        tempM(rowC, 7) = b0 - c3;
    }

    // Transform columns

    for (size_t colC = 0; colC < 8; ++colC)
    {
        // Load 
        a0 = tempM(0, colC);
        a1 = tempM(1, colC);
        a2 = tempM(2, colC);
        a3 = tempM(3, colC);
        a4 = tempM(4, colC);
        a5 = tempM(5, colC);
        a6 = tempM(6, colC);
        a7 = tempM(7, colC);

        // Even part
        // Step 1

        a1 = (a0 >> 1) - a1;
        a0 = a1 - a0;
        a3 += a2 >> 1;
        a2 = (a3 >> 1) - a2;

        // Step 2

        b0 = a0 + a3;
        b3 = a0 - a3;
        b1 = a1 + a2;
        b2 = a1 - a2;

        // Odd part
        // Step 1

        a6 += (a5 >> 1);
        a5 = a6 - a5;
        a7 += a4 >> 2;
        a4 = (a7 >> 2) - a4;

        // Step 2

        c0 = a4 + a5;
        c1 = a4 - a5;
        c2 = a7 - a6;
        c3 = a7 + a6;

        // Step 3

        d0 = (c2 >> 1) - c1;
        d1 = ((d0 * 3) >> 2) - c2;
        d2 = (d1 >> 2) + d0;

        // Step 4

        tempM(0, colC) = b0 + c3;
        tempM(1, colC) = b1 + d1;
        tempM(2, colC) = b2 + d2;
        tempM(3, colC) = b3 + c0;
        tempM(4, colC) = b3 - c0;
        tempM(5, colC) = b2 - d2;
        tempM(6, colC) = b1 - d1;
        tempM(7, colC) = b0 - c3;
    }

    return tempM;
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. What are you asking? If you want help debugging, you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Sorry, edited the post.

Comment: Note that the paper you cite concerns an approximation of the DCT, not DCT itself. Fast algorithms exist for DCT

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But results I get are just wrong (1-2 orders of magnitude off).